# Always open up jQuery UI Model Form in the window

Tags: css, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

All,
I'm using the [jQuery UI Modal Form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) which opens up very nicely for me except for one thing. Sometimes it opens up so only half of it is in the active window and the other half is below the page and I have to drag it up so that the whole form is there. I only changed some of the form elements and colors in the CSS but didn't do anything else in terms of sizing and I also changed the height and width from 300 and 350 to 550 and 600.

How can I ensure that the modal form always opens up in the current window space instead of only half and make sure this happens each time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch the jQuery Dialog, it tries to center on the page.  The first thing I would check is that your HTML and BODY elements are not larger than the default size.  Use firebug to check if there are any styles or DOM attributes causing the HTML and BODY elements to be larger than 100%.  I usually like to reset them like this...

```
html { width:100%; height:100%; }
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. If I drag the screen a little then does this part still work?